# (plain) XeTeX: How can I get the individual bytes from UTF-8 encoded data?

Tags: xetex

I'm working in (plain) XeTeX. I would like to turn an arbitrary macro that has already been read (or even was generated by XeTeX) from XeTeX's internal representation (back) into a utf-8 byte stream, for processing with a complex macro (qrcode generator) that wants the data that way.
At present, the only solution I've found is to use file I.O:

```tex
\input "QRcode.tex" % Vladan Majerech's http://ktiml.mff.cuni.cz/~maj/QRcode.TeX
\mydata{hěłłǒ אֶרֶץ}
\immediate\openout\QRtmpfile="QRtmp.tex"\relax
\immediate\write\QRtmpfile{\string\XeTeXinputencoding "bytes"}%
\immediate\write\QRtmpfile{\string\QRdata"\mydata"}%
\immediate\write\QRtmpfile{\string\endinput}%
\immediate\closeout\QRtmpfile
\input "QRtmp.tex"\relax
\QRcode\box\QRcodebox
\bye
```

Actually writing and reading to the filesystem to recode things seems like it ought to be inefficient. Is this the only way, other than trying to implement a full UTF-8 encoder in TeX? `\scantokens` docs seem to indicate that it skips encoding/decoding, (and testing agrees) so that doesn't help.

Comment: Looking at how the LaTeX project implements `\char_to_utfviii_bytes:n` function by a full UTF-8 encoder in TeX I don't think there's a better way. You may want to read texdoc source3 to see how it's implemented.